# Turn multiple line into one liner with custom separator

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Trivial question. **What is the most elegant function `myfunction` that allows to produce the following output?**

```
# myfunction "a
b
c
d"
a%0Db%0Dc%0Dd%0D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parameter expansion - substitution:

```
myfunction () {
    echo "${1//$'\n'/%0D}"%0D
}
```